# Create a new verb from a noun (for wordplay)

Tags: verbos, sustantivos, adjetivos

In English it's quite easy to do this — you simply add a *to* in front of the noun and you suddenly have a verb. Add a *y* and you have an adjective.

For example:

> fox -> to fox -> foxy

What does to fox mean? I don't know, but it works linguisticly and invites you to play with language.

How do you do this in Spanish? For example with *búho*?

Comment: I know that this is a Spanish language forum, but I can't resist referencing the cartoon Calvin and Hobbes which has the classic line ["Verbing weirds language"](https://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1993/01/25) /s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In English it is not always the case that, by just adding "to" or using a noun as a verb, you get a verb. For example, you don't say "to revolution" but "to revolutionIZE". Nor is it always the case that the result will be a meaningful verb.

However, we do come across cases in Spanish where, by just adding the ending, or changing it to "-ar", "-er", "-ir", we get a verb. The noun and the verb are two different words, that is, we do not, from a lexical point of view, necessarily consider one to derive from the other:

- brillo (brightness) / brill**ar** (to shine)
- temor (fear) / tem**er** (to be afraid)
- suba (increase) / sub**ir** (to rise)

In Spanish, noun-to-verb transformations will always require the addition of a suffix at the end. We don't have a verb for "búho", but we do have one for "lechuza", at least in River Plate Spanish, which is "[lechucear](https://www.asale.org/damer/lechucear)", used to refer to a way of watching similar to that of owls. It is also used to mean "wish somebody bad luck".

[Here](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ndice:Lista_de_sufijos_del_espa%C3%B1ol) is a list of Spanish suffixes. The most productive suffix to convert nouns into verbs is:

**-ear**: agujero (hole) -> agujer**ear** (make a hole) / gol (goal) -> gol**ear** (score a goal)

Another conversion process involves the addition of a prefix (as well as the verbal suffix *-ecer*), either to a noun or an adjective, for example:

- orgullo (pride) / **en**orgull**ecer** (make sb proud)
- rico (rich) / **en**riqu**ecer** (make sb or sth richer)

Comment: I'd say adding **-ear** is by far the most common and acceptable way to create a verb out of just about any word that doesn't have one. Especially if it's just spoken.