# ¿Cuál es la traducción de Calvin y Hobbes: "Verbing weirds language"?

Tags: traducción, verbos, sustantivos

En [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/42873/4251) Ben preguntó sobre la creación de un verbo a partir de un sustantivo.  Esto es algo que podemos hacer en inglés para "jugar" con el idioma.

Yo agregué un comentario refiriéndose a la caricatura de Calvin y Hobbes, donde [Calvin hace un chiste](https://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1993/01/25) que en Inglés dice "Verbing weirds language".  (Publicado en enero 25, 1993)

[image]

Me encanta esta broma en Inglés.  Pero después de escribir mi comentario, encontré pensar ¿cuál es la traducción en español?, y ¿también es un chiste en español parecido al chiste en inglés?

Me gustaría encontrar la traducción oficial de la caricatura de cuando fue publicado.  Pero ahora mismo no la encontro.

Comment: There's not really a joke. However, it is funny. Because he takes a noun  and uses the verb for it (to verb) and also takes weird, an adjective and makes it a verb. Any noun can be verbed in English, not so the adjectives in English. That's why it's funny.

Comment: Hobbes' final comment is particularly meaningful when you try to render this humor into Spansih.

Comment: It looks like that the [newest edition in Spain](https://www.astiberri.com/products/calvin-y-hobbes-el-ataque-de-los-monstruosos-munecos-de-nieve-mutantes) has not reached that point yet. Sadly I don't have the previous one complete to check.

Comment: My 2 cents, `verbing weird languages` ~= enverbar estrambotiza el idioma (jajaja)

Answer (score 2):

Según el diccionario Merriam-Webster, la palabra [verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verb) se utiliza como verbo en inglés desde hace casi un siglo con el sentido que usa Calvin en esta tira. Sin embargo, no es muy habitual, así que la tira juega con ese uso poco habitual. Para reforzarlo, en la última viñeta usa [weird](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weird) también como verbo, y esta palabra ya no aparece como tal en el mismo diccionario.

Para mantener la intención original de la tira, creo que lo mejor es hacer lo mismo en castellano: convertir los sustantivos directamente en verbos, aunque para ello necesitemos añadir terminaciones que el inglés no necesita. Por ejemplo:

> - Me gusta verbar palabras.
> - ¿Qué?

> - Cojo sustantivos y adjetivos y los uso como verbos. ¿Te acuerdas de cuando "[acceso](https://dle.rae.es/accesar)" era una cosa? Ahora es algo que puedo hacer. Ha sido verbado.

> - Verbar rarea el lenguaje.
> - Tal vez podamos llegar a convertir el lenguaje en el impedimento definitivo para la comunicación.

Answer (score 1):

La traducción está en [esta página](https://www.nohaz.co/es/productos):

> “Calvin: Me gusta convertir palabras en verbos.
> Hobbes: Qué?
> Calvin: Cojo nombres y adjetivos y los uso como verbos ¿Recuerdas cuando ‘acceso’ era una cosa? Ahora es algo que haces. Ha sido convertido en verbo.
> Calvin: Verbalizar palabras enrarece las lenguas.
> Hobbes: Quizás al final podamos convertir al lenguaje en un impedimento total para la communicación y el entendimiento.”

Comment: Tienes un enlace a la caricatura/traducción oficial en lugar de a alguna empresa al azar?

Comment: En la pregunta pides la traducción y más allá de la procedencia de la expuesta en la respuesta, es la correcta. Si te interesa la tira cómica, este no es el sitio adecuado para solicitarla.

Comment: No me gusta verbalizar para to verb. Verbalizar is verbalize.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to use nonexistent words in Spanish, like: Verbar extrañece la lengua.

Comment: RAE [verbalizar](https://dle.rae.es/verbalizar): *2. tr. Gram. Convertir en verbo una palabra o un grupo de palabras.*

Comment: Tu traducción es correcta, pero se pierde el efecto del original, que juega con palabras inexistentes.

Comment: El juego de palabras en inglés depende de la falta de conjugación en los verbos en inglés.  El efecto no es igual en español.

Comment: @Danielillo Publicas un enlace a un sitio oficial por el mismo motivo que publicas un enlace a la RAE: para ver la verdad.

Comment: @PeterM Más que la verdad, en este caso sería la traducción "oficial" del chiste en España. Como te apuntaba arriba quizás haya que esperar un poco para que esa tira concreta vuelva a publicarse. Astiberri está en ello. Cuando esté disponible intentaré acordarme de volver por aquí. La edición previa no la tengo completa.